# unable to patch nginx source (can't find file to patch)

Tags: linux, nginx, patch

i'm trying to patch nginx source but it keeps giving me this error

```
[root@server nginx-1.2.6]# patch -p0 < 0004-Accept-variable-name-as-upload_limit_rate-argument.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 14
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|From 8f4cad171fe4fed9cbd11a6a10fb4880e49bf9f6 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
|From: Valentin Dudouyt <valentin.dudouyt@gmail.com>
|Date: Fri, 12 Feb 2016 11:28:56 +0600
|Subject: [PATCH] Accept variable name as upload_limit_rate argument
|
|---
| ngx_http_upload_module.c | 27 +++++++++++++++++----------
| 1 file changed, 17 insertions(+), 10 deletions(-)
|
|diff --git a/ngx_http_upload_module.c b/ngx_http_upload_module.c
|index 93ded70..6bd5027 100644
|--- a/ngx_http_upload_module.c
|+++ b/ngx_http_upload_module.c
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
7 out of 7 hunks ignored
```

why i am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The file you're trying to patch is part of an nginx module ([nginx-upload-module](https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-upload-module)), not part of nginx itself. It wouldn't exist in the nginx source code unless you put it there.
2. The version of nginx you're trying to patch is ancient. The current version is 1.12; the 1.2 branch was last updated in 2013 (1.2.9), and even there it's missing several important security releases.
3. nginx-upload-module is dead. The last commit to the project was in 2008 (9 years ago!!), and the module is incompatible with current versions of nginx.

Comment: thank you duskwuff found my mistake  i placed ngx-http-upload-module in worng directory

Answer (score 0):

Well the file referenced in the patch is not where it is expected to be.
Seems to me the patch is looking for ngx_http_upload_module.c. The *-p0* tells patch to look for this file in your current working directory.

First you have to figure out where the file which is supposed to be patched and then either go into that directory or adjust the *-p* argument